# Mole for VS 2010?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, visualizer, debuggervisualizer

Does anyone know about Karl Shifflett's [Mole](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mole-for-visual-studio/) for VS 2010?

Comment: are there any updates on mole 2010? i have done a few searches but i cant find any thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They released it today.

http://www.molosoft.com @ only 49.00 for 3 activations its a bargain! :)

Comment: That's a surprise it's now commercial. I thought that it was for free.. The price is maybe not that high, but well, you have to pay..

Answer (score 1):

This is from May 20th 2010 in comments:

> We are working on Mole 2010.
>
> The videos for this version are a problem. Silverlight Streaming was shutdown. So for now you can view them here: http://cid-51de981e071f222b.skydrive.live.com/browse.aspx/Public/Mole%20Videos?view=details

That seems to be the most current update I can find, given the changes in the VS ecosystem with plugins, it's a fair amount of work to do the port.  Also, given he has other projects like [XAML Power Toys](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/xaml-power-toys/) going on, this is probably still underway.

Comment: If you catch it before I do, please comment in, I would appreciate any input, this project is essential to WPF and XAML development!

Comment: Here's the latest -august 2010 release date. But no other news so far.
http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/07/16/portland-net-user-group-3-aug-2010-mole-2010/

Answer (score 0):

> October 16, 2010 at 4:33 am
>   Karl Shifflett says:
>
> Mole 2010 will be released in early
>   November. We have put SO much work
>   into this product. We are code
>   complete, working on a nice web site,
>   new videos and docs.

Comment: I don't think it's there yet. They said something about January, but still nothing..

Answer (score 0):

The guys over at Mole have put out a trial version - http://www.molosoft.com/demo/

Cheers!